# A Better way to get these JSON values from properties of a Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I need to grab specific variables from a Class called, `Header`.  I have a `List<Header>` of all of these classes, and am currently doing it this way:

```
protected string _HrefsJson = string.Empty;
protected string _OnClicksJson  = string.Empty;
protected string _TargetsJson = string.Empty;
protected string _TitlesJson = string.Empty;
protected string _CaptionsJson = string.Empty;

List<Header> _HomeHeaderList = _Home.HeaderList.FindAll(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.MobileImage));

IEnumerable<string>     _Titles     = _HomeHeaderList.Select(u => u.Title).ToList();
IEnumerable<string>     _Captions   = _HomeHeaderList.Select(u => u.Caption).ToList();
IEnumerable<string>     _Targets    = _HomeHeaderList.Select(u => u.LinkTarget).ToList();
IEnumerable<string>     _OnClicks   = _HomeHeaderList.Select(u => u.LinkOnClick).ToList();
IEnumerable<string>     _Hrefs      = _HomeHeaderList.Select(u => u.Link).ToList();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
_TitlesJson = jss.Serialize(_Titles);
_CaptionsJson = jss.Serialize(_Captions);
_HrefsJson = jss.Serialize(_Hrefs);
_TargetsJson = jss.Serialize(_Targets);
_OnClicksJson = jss.Serialize(_OnClicks);
```

In my .ascx file, I am getting these strings like so, within a `<script>` tag:

```
var titles = <%=_TitlesJson %>,
    captions = <%= _CaptionsJson %>,
    hrefs = <%= _HrefsJson %>,
    targets = <%= _TargetsJson %>,
    onclicks = <%= _OnClicksJson %>;
```

Thing is, I need to Serialize these values to be passed into javascript as JSON Arrays, but I feel like I am creating to many strings, and doing too many `Select Statements` on the List here.  Is there a way to simplify this for Performance and shorter code perhaps?  Maybe a one-liner or close to it?  I need to maintain index association, that is 0 to `(_HomeHeaderList.Count - 1)`, so this is the only way I could think to do this.  But it just seems sloppy to me.

The reason I need to maintain the indexes of each of these is because, in Javascript I am using these values of each index to write them as text.

Thanks

The values from the Json Arrays need to be inputted into this Html Structure:

```
<div class="mobile-text-wrapper" data-target="#mobileCarousel" role="overlay">
    <div class="pnova-bold mobile-title"></div>
    <div class="tisa-italic mobile-caption"></div>
</div>
<a class="mobile-overlay-link"></a>
```

The jQuery I'm using is like this:

```
<script>
    var titles = <%=_TitlesJson %>,
        captions = <%= _CaptionsJson %>,
        hrefs = <%= _HrefsJson %>,
        targets = <%= _TargetsJson %>,
        onclicks = <%= _OnClicksJson %>,
        slideIndex = 0;

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".mobile-title").text(titles[slideIndex]);
        $(".mobile-caption").text(captions[slideIndex]);
        $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("href", hrefs[slideIndex]);

        if (targets[slideIndex] != "")
            $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("target", targets[slideIndex]);

        if (onclicks[slideIndex] != "")
            $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("onclick", onclicks[slideIndex]);

        // On Slide Before
        $('#mobileCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
            $(".mobile-text-wrapper").fadeOut("fast");
        });

        // On Slide After
        $('#mobileCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
            slideIndex = $('#mobileCarousel .active').index('#mobileCarousel .item');

            $(".mobile-title").text(titles[slideIndex]);
            $(".mobile-caption").text(captions[slideIndex]);
            $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("href", hrefs[slideIndex]);

            if (targets[slideIndex] != "")
                $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("target", targets[slideIndex]);

            if (onclicks[slideIndex] != "")
                $(".mobile-overlay-link").attr("onclick", onclicks[slideIndex]);

            $(".mobile-text-wrapper").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just serialise the List you're getting, then accessing each field in it?

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
_HomeHeaderJson = jss.Serialize(_HomeHeaderList);
```

Then in the .ascx file, you should be able to do:

```
var title = <%=_HomeHeaderJson[0].Title %>
```

Obviously, you'll need to add a loop in the ascx file to get each item in turn, but this approach keeps all the data together.

EDIT:

To update your javascript, you should be able to just use the slideIndex on the _HomeHeaderJson then get each field.

Eg.

```
var data = <%=_HomeHeaderJson %>
$(".mobile-title").text(data[slideIndex].Title);
$(".mobile-caption").text(data[slideIndex].Caption);
etc etc...
```

Comment: Interesting, so I am now thinking that the Javascript for the Json Arrays will need to change, though, not sure how now...  Thinking of something like a .push to an array.  Can you provide a small example of this please?

Comment: Can you post the javascript in your original question?